# Issue with code for connecting to VPN

Tags: ios, swift, vpn, ipsec

I am creating an app the allows you to connect to a VPN at the tap of a button.  I've been experimenting with the code, and I receive an error Use of unresolved identifier 'getPasscodeNSData'.  I Googled everywhere but I could not find a way to solve this.  Thank you in advance, I will leave the chunk of code below.

```
func initVPN() {
    let manager: NEVPNManager = NEVPNManager.sharedManager()
    let p = NEVPNProtocolIPSec()

    p.username = "vpnUser"
    p.passwordReference = getPasscodeNSData("vpnPassword")
    p.serverAddress = "vpnIP"
    p.authenticationMethod = NEVPNIKEAuthenticationMethod.SharedSecret
    p.sharedSecretReference = getPasscodeNSData("vpnSharedSecret")
    p.useExtendedAuthentication = true
    p.disconnectOnSleep = false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you copied this code from someone. getPasscodeNSData is a function that this person wrote. You need to copy that function too.